# iPhone - Parsing XML file - Please help!

Tags: iphone, xml, uitableview, nsxmlparser

I need help with parsing a xml file. My problem is I don't know how to implement the didEndElement delegate.
What I want is that I will have 2 cells where Old Testament and New Testament will be displayed and then the Books of the Bible and the the chapters.
If I can just get some help with the xml parsing the rest I can manage.

Will be very grateful for any help!

Thanks and regards!

My xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bible>
 <testament name="Old Testament">
  <book name="Genesis">
   <chapter id="Genesis 1"></chapter>
   <chapter id="Genesis 2"></chapter>
  </book>
  <book name="Exodus">
   <chapter id="Exodus 1"></chapter>
   <chapter id="Exodus 2"></chapter>
  </book>
 </testament>
 <testament name="New Testament">
  <book name="Matthew">
   <chapter id="Matthew 1"></chapter>
   <chapter id="Matthew 2"></chapter>
  </book>
  <book name="Revelation">
   <chapter id="Revelation 1"></chapter>
   <chapter id="Revelation 2"></chapter>
  </book>
 </testament>
</bible>
```

---

```
//  Bible.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Bible : NSObject {
 NSMutableArray *bible;
 NSMutableArray *testament;
 NSMutableArray *book;
 NSString *chapterID;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *bible;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *testament;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *book;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *chapterID;

@end
```

---

```
//  Bible.m

#import "Bible.h"


@implementation Bible

@synthesize bible;
@synthesize testament;
@synthesize book;
@synthesize chapterID;

- (void) dealloc {
 [bible release];
 [testament release];
 [book release];
 [chapterID release];
 [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

---

```
//
//  XMLParser.h
//  BibleXML
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Bible.h"

@protocol NSXMLParserDelegate;

@class BibleXMLAppDelegate, Bible;

@interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {


 NSMutableString *currentElementValue;

 BibleXMLAppDelegate *appDelegate;
 Bible *theBible;

}

- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser;

@end
```

---

```
//
//  XMLParser.m

#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "BibleXMLAppDelegate.h"
#import "Bible.h"


@implementation XMLParser

- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser {

 [super init];

 appDelegate = (BibleXMLAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 return self;
}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{ 
 NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
 attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"bible"]) {
  NSLog(@"Found element: %@", elementName);
  appDelegate.bible = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 }

 else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"testament"]) {

  theBible = [[Bible alloc] init];
  //Extract the attribute here.
  theBible.testament = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"name"];
  NSLog(@"Testament: %@", theBible.testament);
  return;
 }

 else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"book"])
 {
  theBible.book = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"name"];
  NSLog(@"Book: %@", theBible.book);
  return;
 }

 else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"chapter"]) 
 {
  theBible.chapterID =[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"];
  NSLog(@"Chapter: %@", theBible.chapterID);
  return;
 } 
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"bible"]){
   return;
 } 

}


- (void) dealloc {
 [theBible release];
 [currentElementValue release];
 [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

---

Following is the output from the debugger console:

```
2010-12-08 19:53:10.101 BibleXML[25641:207] found file and started parsing
2010-12-08 19:53:10.102 BibleXML[25641:207] Found element: bible
2010-12-08 19:53:10.103 BibleXML[25641:207] Testament: Old Testament
2010-12-08 19:53:10.103 BibleXML[25641:207] Book: Genesis
2010-12-08 19:53:10.104 BibleXML[25641:207] Chapter: Genesis 1
2010-12-08 19:53:10.104 BibleXML[25641:207] Chapter: Genesis 2
2010-12-08 19:53:10.105 BibleXML[25641:207] Book: Exodus
2010-12-08 19:53:10.105 BibleXML[25641:207] Chapter: Exodus 1
2010-12-08 19:53:10.106 BibleXML[25641:207] Chapter: Exodus 2
2010-12-08 19:53:10.107 BibleXML[25641:207] Testament: New Testament
2010-12-08 19:53:10.107 BibleXML[25641:207] Book: Matthew
2010-12-08 19:53:10.108 BibleXML[25641:207] Chapter: Matthew 1
2010-12-08 19:53:10.108 BibleXML[25641:207] Chapter: Matthew 2
2010-12-08 19:53:10.109 BibleXML[25641:207] Book: Revelation
2010-12-08 19:53:10.109 BibleXML[25641:207] Chapter: Revelation 1
2010-12-08 19:53:10.110 BibleXML[25641:207] Chapter: Revelation 2
2010-12-08 19:53:10.110 BibleXML[25641:207] No Errors
```

Comment: Dont roll back my edits again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is completely and utterly unreadable. Please use the "101010" button to format your code, and check the preview before you hit post. If you can't read it, then how can we read it?

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying figure how to do just that. Thank you Richard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already parsing it. In the `didEndElement:` call, just do whatever you want to do with the element. Since your XML doesn't contain any wrapped strings (you're not using `foundCharacters:`), all you have to do is respond to `didStartElement:` and `didEndElement:` accordingly. If you need to capture attributes or allocate a new data structure to hold possible children, do it in `didStartElement:`. If you need to save off objects into collections or somehow finish processing of a particular element, do it in `didEndElement:`.

This question isn't really about parsing, it's about whatever logic you want to enact in response to parsing.

**Edit in response to comment below:**

I typically do the following to save off objects during parsing: in my interface, I declare the collection I need to save objects into and a temporary object that I used to hold whatever data I need to before adding it to the collection, like this

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *collection_;
    SomeObject *tempObject_;
}
@end
```

In the implementation I manipulate these two objects, typically in `didStartDocument`:, `didStartElement:` and `didEndElement:`, like so:

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    collection_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    //if your object is tied to a tag that wraps text (delivered in foundCharacters:), initialize it here
    tempObject_ = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
    //maybe you need the attributes....
    tempObject_.someProperty = [attributes objectForKey:@"attribute-name"];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    //when the tag ends, you can save it off into the collection
    [collection_ addObject:tempObject_];
    [tempObject_ release];
    tempObject_ = nil;
}
```

Then do what you will with the collection object. Make sure you handle memory things, like releasing the collection object or whatever. I usually use something like a delegate callback (of my own devising) to get the collection to the model, in order to logically separate parsing from the model.

Comment: Hi Kevboh, I appreciate your help with this. I am in fact trying to "save off objects into collections". That's just where I'm running into problems. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Kevboh, Thank you very much! This is a great help to me! I can manage from here.

Comment: Hi Kevboh, Thanks a lot! Great to know that there are people like you who take the time to lend a helping hand!